# How to Return Values Using Rows and Columns as Variables (i, j)?

Tags: excel, variables, row

I am trying to redesign a table to ease the analysis and use of formulas in it.
What I basically have is a list of customers and a column to each State. If the customer has a document to that state, the cell is filled in with the expiration date of the document, otherwise the cell remains empty.
The new table I want to create must bring the list of documents by customer and by state. So instead of having 50 columns for the 50 States of US, I will have a column named "State" and another column returning the "Expiration Date" of the document. This new table would ignore the blank cells from the first table, what means the customer does not have the required document.
I built the macro, but it runs with no errors but also NO CHANGES. Simply nothing happens. So what am I doing wrong?

```
Sub AllCertificates()

' Define variables
    Dim DataBase As Range
        Set DataBase = Sheets("DataBase").Range("A2:BA10000")
    Dim DataBaseH As Range
        Set DataBaseH = Sheets("DataBase").Range("A1:BA1")
    Dim nStates As Integer
        nStates = DataBase.Columns.Count
    Dim nCustomers As Long
        nCustomers = DataBase.Rows.Count
    Dim nCerts As Long
        nCerts = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .Count(Sheets("DataBase").Range("J2:BA10000"))
    Dim nData As Long
        nData = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .Count(Sheets("All Certificates").Columns(1)) + 1
    Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To nCustomers
    Dim j As Long
        For j = 6 To nStates

' Transfer data to "All Certificates"
    If DataBase.Cells(i, j).Value = "*" Then
        ' Returns the "Customer ID"
        Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 1).Value = DataBase.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ' Returns the "Customer Name"
        Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 2).Value = DataBase.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ' Returns the "State"
        Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 3).Value = DataBaseH.Cells(1, j).Value
        ' Returns the "Expiration Date"
        Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 4).Value = DataBase.Cells(i, j).Value
        End If

        Next j
        Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See below for what should be a working version of your code. Corrections include:

1.) Application.WorksheetFunction.Count only counts numerical values.  You need to use Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA

2.) The * character is a literal when used inside a VBA string, not a wildcard.  Instead, use something like value <> "".

3.) You need to increment you nData value.  It's not going to recalculate that original assignment unless you place it inside the loop, but it's computationally much quicker to just increment with n = n + 1.

4.) Minor formatting things. Pay special attention to formatting loops and conditional statements especially or you'll wind up typing something wrong.

```
Sub AllCertificates()
'Define variables
Dim DataBase As Range
    Set DataBase = Sheets("DataBase").Range("A2:BA10000")
Dim DataBaseH As Range
    Set DataBaseH = Sheets("DataBase").Range("A1:BA1")
Dim nStates As Integer
    nStates = DataBase.Columns.Count
Dim nCustomers As Long
    nCustomers = DataBase.Rows.Count
Dim nCerts As Long
    nCerts = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("DataBase").Range("C2:BA10000"))
Dim nData As Long
    nData = Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .CountA(Sheets("All Certificates").Columns(1)) + 1
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To nCustomers
        For j = 6 To nStates
        ' Transfer data to "All Certificates"
            If DataBase.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                ' Returns the "Customer ID"
                Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 1).Value = DataBase.Cells(i, 1).Value
                ' Returns the "Customer Name"
                Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 2).Value = DataBase.Cells(i, 2).Value
                ' Returns the "State"
                Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 3).Value = DataBaseH.Cells(1, j).Value
                ' Returns the "Expiration Date"
                Sheets("All Certificates").Cells(nData, 4).Value = DataBase.Cells(i, j).Value
                nData = nData + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Note:** Your question is relatively specific.  A StackOverflow question is supposed to address issues that many people can learn from, not just a one-off solution.  I think the biggest lesson to learn from your question is how to debug.  A little use of breakpoints, step-into (F8), and variable watching and you would have been able to get this macro running on your own with no problem.

[Debugging (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172744.aspx)
[Breakpoints (WiseOwl)](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm)

You may want to consider editing your original question and/or adding a debug keyword since the information you really needed was about general debugging.  Also, you may want to edit it to included the problems fixes as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you DanT, for the help and the tips.
I made the changes you proposed and the Macro worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear.  It'd be great if you could accept this answer then and edit the original question per my suggestions about debugging.